# Another term for "honest lying"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Sometimes we mistakenly think something is true and so we tell it to others; Unbeknownst to us, the thing is not true. How to call such untruthfulness?

> Example:
>
> A: You told me she will not be in this party. You lied to me.
>
> B: No, I didn't know that myself. She told me she is out of town.

In the above scenario, what B had said to A was a "honest lie".

["Honest lie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie#Honest_lie) has been used for such untruthfulness. But I need other words/terms/phrases for that. And I need a verb, something meaning "honest lying".

There is also this word "confabulate" [same source] which is more of technical usages and means mistakenly and with no intention taking something false as true. But this is obviously not what I want.

Comment: I've never noticed *honest lie* nor anything like it and I've been listening for 60 years. When it's *commonly used* could you provide some examples, please?

*Untruthfulness* is not comparable to *lacking truth*. *Lies* are deliberate.

What would be wrong with *mistake* or *error*?

Comment: I never heard of "honest lie" either. A **lie** is something that is *known to be false*.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I added an example to the question. Word such as "mistake" and "error" are two broad. I want a word to describe that kind of "saying false things to others unintentionally". "Honest lie" is good but when I turn it into a verb as "honest lying" then it sounds odd.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sounds like a pretty common term for example on Google Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=honest+lie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chonest%20lie%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sasan, where did you get this idea? As Weather Vane says *A lie is something known to be false*. Why d'you doubt that?

You’re welcome to amend the Question but as it was posted, words such as *mistake* or *error* perfectly describe what you asked about.

No phrase nor word describes *saying false things to others unintentionally*. *Honest lie* is not good, turned into a verb or not.

What seems to have happened is that you’ve been misled; misinformed or are what you would call but I never would, *honestly lying*.

Comment: Probably in English, something is a "lie" only if the speaker knows it is false.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't doubt that a lie is something known to be false. Phrases or expressions are not always made based on precise definitions. Honest Lie is there used to mean what I said.

Comment: Sasan, I'm sorry but you very clearly doubt a lie is something known to be false; that's the only meaning of anything you've said. Will you now please be specific? In your entire life, roughly how many times have heard the phrase *honest lying*?

Of those, how many were from native speakers?

It's doesn't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure but is confabulation the right word?

Comment: there is no word or phrase for that in English afaik.

Comment: I think a lie is a statement made with the intent to deceive.  Regardless of whether the statement is true or false.

Comment: @Sasan Did you follow through with any off the actual search results? Many are false positives eg picking up the ends of two sentences eg "Now, be honest!" Lie 2 "No, I didn't do it." or refer to really intentional lies, the opposite of your accidental misinformation. *Where* is it you hear this usage? What country? It may be a term familiar to your local English that is not current elsewhere.

Comment: @Spagirl I also mentioned the Wikipedia link where it is referenced to a book.

Comment: @Sasan For one thing, that doesn't address any of the questions I posed to you; for another, I can't see any reference to wikipedia, links or books in your question or any of your comments.

Comment: @Spagirl Sorry, my mistake. I just added the link.

Answer (score 4):

When I say something which I believe to be true it is said in **good faith**.

> No, I said that in good faith. She told me she is out of town.

As [defined here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good_faith) by Oxford online dictionary.

You also use the phrase

> Unbeknownst to us, the thing is not true.

which can be said as

> This was a misconception.

Even if some people do say "honest lie", I would not because a lie has the *intention* to deceive, so it cannot be *honest*.

**Edit** after a comment from OP. The sentence

> You lied to me.

Can be rephrased with less accusation as

> You misled me.

Conversely,

> I am sorry I misled you.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I am looking for a verb in that sense.

Comment: @Sasan I edited the answer.

Comment: But "mislead" can be both *intentional* and *unintentional*.

Comment: @Sasan yes, so **I did not intend to mislead you**.

Answer (score 1):

honest mistake.  it's not a lie if it is unintentional.